# MySQL Database - Related Results from same table / Many to Many database design problem

Tags: mysql, database, hierarchical-data

I am designing a relational database of products where there are products that are copies/bootlegs of each other, and I'd like to be able to show that through the system.

So initially during my first draft, I had a field in products called " isacopyof " thinking to just list a comma delimited list of productIDs that are copies of the current product.

Obviously once I started implementing, that wasn't going to work out.

So far, most many-to-many relationship solutions revolve around an associative table listing related id from table A and related id from table B. That works, but my situation involves related items from the SAME table of products...

How can I build a solution around that ? Or maybe I am thinking in the wrong direction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking.

If you have a `products` table with a `productid` key, you can have a `clones` table with `productid1` and `productid2` fields mapping from `products` to `products` and a multi-key on both fields.  No issue, and it's still 3NF.

Comment: oh my goodness.. I AM overthinking.. I totally assumed that the clone table needed to have ids from 2 different sources... thanks for clearing my head!

Answer (score 2):

Because something is a copy, that means you have a parent and child relationship... Hierarchical data.

You're on the right track for the data you want to model.  Rather than have a separate table to hold the relationship, you can add a column to the existing table to hold the parent_id value--the primary key value indicating the parent to the current record.  This is [an excellent read about handling hierarchical data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)...

Sadly, MySQL doesn't have hierarchical query syntax, which for things like these I highly recommend looking at those that do:

- PostgreSQL (free)
- SQL Server (Express is free)
- Oracle (Express is also free)

Comment: thanks for the insight and article.. I think this may be something I'll face, but not this particular instance because I could have multiple copies of the same product, so a product might have 2 parentIDs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you can't have links to the same product table in your 'links' table.

There are a few ways to do this, but a basic design might simply be 2 columns:

```
ProductID1, ProductID2
```

Where both these columns link back to ProductID in your product table. If you know which is the 'real' product and which is the copy, you might have logic/constraints which place the 'real' productID in ProductID1 and the 'copy' productID in ProductID2.

Comment: hmm ok, you brought up an interesting point which I missed, so I may have to have a ' is_original ' field to mark a 'real' product...

Comment: If it doesn't matter whether a copy is a direct copy or a copy of a copy, I think the hierarchical approach is probably overkill; I'd just use the link table. Good idea to maintain a flag for originals.